# How to fix Type does not contain a definition for 'Show' and no extension method could be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

Hello everyone how are you? I'm fine.
I'm trying to write the scripts for a Unity3d game monetization.
I've written the script to initialize the Admob ads and now I'm writting another script for Load and Show the ads. I'm following the Admob tutorial, but I have some errors that I don't know how to fix.

> The type 'InterstitialAd' does not contain a constructor that takes '1' arguments
>
> Type 'InterstitialAd' does not contain a definition for 'LoadAd' and no extension method 'LoadAd' of type 'InterstitialAd' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
>
> Type 'InterstitialAd' does not contain a definition for 'IsLoaded' and no extension method 'IsLoaded' of type 'InterstitialAd' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
>
> Type 'InterstitialAd' does not contain a definition for 'Show' and no extension method 'Show' of type 'InterstitialAd' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

It seems that I have to write a constructor, and the methods are not defined but I'm following the instructions of AdMob monetization guide, and It's supposed that using the Admob api will load the methods, but it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

    public class InterstitialAd : MonoBehaviour 
    {
        private InterstitialAd interstitial;
        private string adUnitId;

        private void requestInterstitial() 
        {
            //Los siguientes adUnitId son anuncios de prueba, antes de publicarlo debo reemplazar adUnitId con el id del bloque de anuncios
#if UNITY_ANDROID
            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910";
#else
            string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
#endif

            // Initialize an InterstitialAd. //Id Del bloque de anuncios
            this.interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
            // Use this for initialization
            // Create an empty ad request.
            AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
            //Load the interstitial with the request interstitial
             this.interstitial.LoadAd(request);
        }

        //ShowAd
        private void showInterstitial() 
        {
            if (Time.time % 45 == 0 && Time.timeSinceLevelLoad > 60 && this.interstitial.IsLoaded()) 
            {
                this.interstitial.Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope you can help me! It's the final step for publishing my app !

Comment: `class InterstitialAd : MonoBehaviour` does not have constructor with one argument... So what is exactly unclear to you about those error messages? (We have no ide what is that "AdMob monetization guide" you are following and why your wrote such code - consider adding link to that at least (in addition to [edit] of the post with explanation why you expect your class to have a constructor with one argument when you did not provide one)

Comment: Side note: having class with field of the same class is unusual - there is a good chance that you really don't want to name your behavior `InterstitialAd `...

Comment: Sorry Alexei, this is the admob guide https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start?hl=es

Comment: I'm not expecting to have a constructor, I have written the cody exactly as google requires, but still having errors. I'm going to change the name of the class, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have a name conflict there between your own class `InterstitialAd : MonoBehaviour` and the already existing `GoogleMobileAds.Api.InterstitialAd`

So when you do

```
private InterstitialAd interstitial;

new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);

this.interstitial.LoadAd(request);

this.interstitial.IsLoaded()

this.interstitial.Show();
```

it always tries to do those on your own `InterstitialAd : MonoBehaviour` type which doesn't implement those Properties/Methods.

---

You either have to rename your class like e.g.

```
public class IntersitialAdController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    ...
}
```

If you do that make sure also the name of the file is changed to mirror exactly the Behviours name `IntersitialAdController.cs` (on drive) or without the `.cs` in Unity's `Project` view.

Or alternatively access the correct type via its full namespace everywhere:

```
private GoogleMobileAds.Api.InterstitialAd interstitial;

new GoogleMobileAds.Api.InterstitialAd(adUnitId);

etc ...
```